# Determine function return in Access Database Immediate window script

Tags: ms-access

I have created an Access Database which contains all patients from our private healthcare who have had appointments booked in the past year.

The database contains fields such as 'patient ID, Name, Date, Value etc.".

In the value field, some patients have notes such as 'Mental health' or 'Broken Bone'.
I have created a function in Access which substitutes a word in the Value field with something else. For example, with Mental Health i would change it to Depression.

```
Option Compare Database
```

Option Explicit

Public Function MapDiagnosis( _
                strDiagnosis As String) _
                As String
'map diagnosis to friendly name
If InStr(strDiagnosis, "Mental Health") > 0 Then
    MapDiagnosis = "depression"
Else
    If InStr(strDiagnosis, "Gyneacological") > 0 Then
        MapDiagnosis = "pregnant"
    Else

```
    MapDiagnosis = "other"
If InStr(strDiagnosis, "Gastritis") > 0 Then
    MapDiagnosis = "indigestion"
Else

If InStr(strDiagnosis, "Muscular") > 0 Then
    MapDiagnosis = "muscle pain"
Else

If InStr(strDiagnosis, "Cardiovascular") > 0 Then
    MapDiagnosis = "heart"
Else

If InStr(strDiagnosis, "Broken Bones") > 0 Then
    MapDiagnosis = "Fracture"
Else

If InStr(strDiagnosis, "No underlying cause") > 0 Then
    MapDiagnosis = "None"

End If

End If

End If

End If

End If

End If
```

End If

What I don't know how to do is run the script on the 'Immediate' window on VBA which allows me to determine if the words will change.

The script is below.

```
?MapDiagnosis(strDiagnosis) = "Mental Health"
```

I'm not sure why the above script is not running on the immediate window.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try `?MapDiagnosis("Mental Health")`

Comment: @GordThompson please see my comment under my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type:

```
?MapDiagnosis("Mental Health")
```

Into the Immediate window.

Comment: This question didn't have an answer so I felt one needed to be posted for the community, plus I was looking for a few points. But if @GordThompson posts an answer, I will gladly delete mine.

Comment: I appreciate the concern expressed by @SargeBorsch but I'm okay with you posting your answer. Cheers!